# Using a before_filter in application_controller to access a model in application.html.erb leads to unexpected html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to access a model in my application.html.erb file. For this I defined a before_filter in the application_controller.rb:

```
before_filter :populate_ages

protected

def populate_ages
  @ages= Ages.all
end
```

In my application.html.erb I have the following:

```
<%= @ages.each do |age| %>
  <p><%= age.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

The names are rendered correctly but I get additional output which is the array @ages. It looks like this:

```
[#&lt;ageid: 1, name: &quot;Herren&quot;, created_at: &quot;2014-06-26 08:02:58&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2014-06-26 08:02:58&quot;&gt;, #&lt;ageid: 2, name: &quot;A-Jugend&quot;, created_at: &quot;2014-06-26 08:02:58&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2014-06-26 08:02:58&quot;&gt;, #&lt;ageid: 3, name: &quot;B-Jugend&quot;, created_at: &quot;2014-06-26 08:02:58&quot;, updated_at: &quot;2014-06-26 08:02:58&quot;&gt;]           </ul>
```

I have this code in a navigation bar. So my navigation bar is extended by this additional text. Adding the loop in the body leads to the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the = sign on the loop, change it to:

```
<% @ages.each do |age| %>
  <p><%= age.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

By having `<%= @ages ...` you're telling rails to display the array

Answer (score 1):

Just write as

```
<% @ages.each do |age| %>
  <p><%= age.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

`@ages` is an `Array` instance. Now [`Array#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-each) returns the *receiver* itself, when full iteration is completed. `<%=.. %>` means you are telling execute the each m,method and print the result of the `#each` method too, which is the problem, you have faced. Thus tell your template executed the method, don't print the result of it, and to do this correct syntax is `<%.. %>`.